# Does localhost resolve to the same thing on virtual and host machines?

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, localhost

If I set up a web server in a virtual machine, will `localhost`/`127.0.0.1` be the same on both the virtual and the host machine?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely if `/etc/hosts` isn't changed on either of them.

Note that 127.0.0.1 is an address given to the loopback interface, i.e it never leaves the machine.

Read more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: +1 and adding: So assuming the non-modified version of /etc/hosts, locallhost of a vm will be different than localhost of its host. If you want to access host's service from vm, you can use bridged networking or a host only interface, i believe.